# TypeError: Invalid parameters passed: {'n_samples': 16000}

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am trying to use train_test_split from package scikit Learn, but I am having trouble with parameter.
here is my code

```
files = glob.glob(DATA_DIR + "*.wav")
X_train, X_val = train_test_split(files, n_samples=16000, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8, random_state=SEED)

print('# Training examples: {}'.format(len(X_train)))
print('# Validation examples: {}'.format(len(X_val)))
```

here is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-14b557c632f0> in <module>
      1 files = glob.glob(DATA_DIR + "*.wav")
----> 2 X_train, X_val = train_test_split(files, n_samples=16000, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8, random_state=SEED)
      3 
      4 print('# Training examples: {}'.format(len(X_train)))
      5 print('# Validation examples: {}'.format(len(X_val)))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2092 
   2093     if options:
-> 2094         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2095 
   2096     arrays = indexable(*arrays)

TypeError: Invalid parameters passed: {'n_samples': 16000}
```

Comment: `train_test_split()` doesn't have argument named `n_samples`

Comment: when i didn't use n_samples. then this error comes up 

ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=0.8, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: what you mean by didn't use do you removed that argument are just set it zero

Comment: i've tried remove that argument, i'm new in python. Thank u so much.